# Mapping a future in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'm trying to do some response processing using the Dio flutter package

I have the following function

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> forgotPassword(Map body) => client.dio
  .post('/user/forgotpassword', data: body)
  .then(
      (response) => {
            print('POST /user/forgotpassword $response'),
            response.data as Map<String, dynamic>
          },
      onError: (error) => {
        throw error
        })
  .catchError((error) => client.handleRequestError(error));
```

I expected this to return a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`, which I specify on `response.data as Map<String, dynamic>` but I get a `dart(return_of_invalid_type)` error from the compiler.

```
A value of type 'Future<Set<void>> can't be returned from method 'forgotPassword' because it has a return type of 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
```

What is the correct way to return map this Future's value into a Map (or any other class, for that matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some weird syntax in the callback of your `.then`. If you drop the `=>` notation, things should work:

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> forgotPassword(Map body) => client.dio
  .post('/user/forgotpassword', data: body)
  .then(
      (response) {
            print('POST /user/forgotpassword $response'),
            response.data as Map<String, dynamic>
          },
      onError: (error) => {
        throw error
        })
  .catchError((error) => client.handleRequestError(error));
```

Only use `=>` for single line statements as it returns the result of the statement. The reason you're seeing a return type of `Future<Set<void>>` is because you're creating a `Set` by doing `(response) => { /* this is treated as a Set */ }`

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :-)